# Python: fill a row of a pandas dataframe with a column of an numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (1413 rows) and a numpy array (1412 rows).

```
type(df1)
Out[193]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

df1.shape
Out[194]: (1413, 15)

type(arr1)
Out[195]: numpy.ndarray

arr1.shape
Out[196]: (1412, 3)
```

I would like to fill a column in the df1 with a column in arr1 + nan, but it does not work

```
df1['aaa'] = np.vstack((np.nan, arr1[:,0]))
```

Could anyone let me know how to do it?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do with `np.nan`. Where do you want it to be ?

Comment: Do you need add missing value to last position or to first? Also what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: @Johnny - If ask under his question, not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) for add one value to `1d` array:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(6)})

arr1 = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
print (arr1)
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]]

df1['aaa'] = np.hstack((np.nan, arr1[:,0]))
print (df1)
   a   aaa
0  0   NaN
1  1   0.0
2  2   3.0
3  3   6.0
4  4   9.0
5  5  12.0
```

---

Another idea if possible non default index of `DataFrame` is use `Series` constructor with indexing `df1.index`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(6)}, index=list('abcdef'))

arr1 = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
print (arr1)
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]]

dif = df1.shape[0] - arr1.shape[0]
df1['aaa'] = pd.Series(arr1[:,0], index=df1.index[dif:])
print (df1)
   a   aaa
a  0   NaN
b  1   0.0
c  2   3.0
d  3   6.0
e  4   9.0
f  5  12.0
```

Last position:

```
dif = df1.shape[0] - arr1.shape[0]
df1['aaa'] = pd.Series(arr1[:,0], index=df1.index[:-dif])
print (df1)
   a   aaa
a  0   0.0
b  1   3.0
c  2   6.0
d  3   9.0
e  4  12.0
f  5   NaN
```

EDIT:

```
arr1 = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(6)})
```

If select by `0` only get `1d` array with shape `(6,)`, so is necessary [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
a = np.hstack((np.nan, arr1[:,0]))
print (a)
[nan  0.  3.  6.  9. 12.]

print (a.shape)
(6,)

df1['aaa'] = a
```

If select by `[0]` get `2d` array with dimensions `MxN` with shape `(6,1)`, so is possible use [`numpy.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
a1 = np.vstack((np.nan, arr1[:,[0]]))
print (a1)
[[nan]
 [ 0.]
 [ 3.]
 [ 6.]
 [ 9.]
 [12.]]

print (a1.shape)
(6, 1)


df1['aaa1'] = a1
print (df1)
   a   aaa  aaa1
0  0   NaN   NaN
1  1   0.0   0.0
2  2   3.0   3.0
3  3   6.0   6.0
4  4   9.0   9.0
5  5  12.0  12.0
```

Comment: The command "hstack" works!! But why is it "hstack" rather than "vstack"? Very counterintuitive.

Comment: @user2644687 - I edit answer and try explain it, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, here you have the result. You add the column and the first line is NaN:

```py
df['aaa'] = pd.Series(ar1[:,0])
ea = np.empty(df.shape[1]).fill(np.nan)
df.loc[-1] = ea
df.index = df.index + 1
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(by=['aaa'], na_position='first')
```

Here is your DataFrame:

```
c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
1  10  20  30
```

Here is the array:

```
[[  5  55]
 [ 50 550]]
```

And the result is this :

```
     c1    c2    c3   aaa
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
0   1.0   2.0   3.0   5.0
1  10.0  20.0  30.0  50.0
```

Comment: "First position" is ambiguous. What do you mean by that, exactly? Which row, which column?

Comment: @jezrael  yes, you are right, but I think it is better to teach a man to fish than to give him the fish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

```py
df1['aaa'] = np.append(np.nan, arr1[:,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can see several other answers, none of them have really addressed the problem at hand. Intuitively, your approach is okay; you're stacking `nan` vertically on a column array.

```
df1['aaa'] = np.vstack((np.nan, arr1[:,0]))
```

It should work, but it doesn't. The small problem here is that `vstack` searches for a column dimension. `arr1[:,0]` has the shape `(1412, )`; it doesn't have a second dimension. Simple reshaping it to `(1412,1)` will make `vstack` work just fine.

```
df1['aaa'] = np.vstack((np.nan, arr1[:,0].reshape(-1,1)))
```